# List all the Products that have never sold a single item. Only show the product names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to use the Adventurewalks2017 database for this...again.

[image: Database Diagram]

```
SELECT Distinct Name
FROM Production.Product P
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD on SOD.ProductID = P.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH on SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
WHERE SOD.SalesOrderID NOT IN (
SELECT SOD.ProductID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE SalesOrderID = NULL
)
ORDER BY Name
```

The result of this is too large and im thinking really wrong, since I checked the ID's and some items have indeed sold.

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` to  `Sales.SalesOrderDetail` and `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` here? Don't you *actually* just want a `NOT EXISTS` from the table `Production.Product`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this

```
select p.[Name] 
from Production.Product P
where not exists (select 1
                  from Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
                  where p.ProductID = sod.ProductID)
order by p.[Name];
```